# Generating a Static Map Efficiently

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple parser in C++ that works using a map of string 'triggers' to 'handler' function pointers, my question is what would be the most 'static' and efficient method of implementing generation and access to the map?

I first considered a method, e.g. `Parser::add_handler`, that would add the trigger/handler to the parser's map, but, as far as I know, this would need to be executed every time the program was ran whilst the data is known at compile time.  (Although on the plus side, they would only need executed once, and not for each instantiated Parser.)

I then thought of using a virtual method, e.g. `Parser::get_handlers` in Parser that would be implemented in derived classes to return the handler map for that parser.  This seems like a more nicely encapsulated solution although it would require a virtual function call for every created instance of the parser, with at least one call to the parser's map-generating function.

Using the latter approach seems preferable at the moment, but it still leaves the map to be generated dynamically on each execution, is there away to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to build the map dynamically, you can use a sorted static array with `std::lower_bound` to search it in O(log n) time.

If you have a good hash map implementation available, you might find that the overhead of populating it is less than the performance gain at runtime, depending on how many lookups you need to do.

Comment: I think `std::map ` is probably the way forward, as there will rarely be much more than, say, 10 elements in the map versus potentially thousands of lines in the source file, with all lines matching a trigger requiring a lookup.

Comment: The array with `std::lower_bound` can be faster than `std::map`. If performance is an issue you should try both.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  I doubt performance will be an issue but nice to know I've got an alternative if it is.

Comment: How about a hash? O(1) is better than O(n).

Comment: Would it not be `O(lg n)` if `std::map` uses a binary search?  Either way a hash would be preferable but I can't see one in `std` (which seems like a bit of an oversight, really, as it's a fairly common data structure).

Comment: @connect: there is `std::unordered_map` in C++0x or `std::tr1::unordered_map` in C++03. Well, unless you are using some rare or very old compiler.

Comment: @Vlad, Both `std::map` and `std::lower_bound` are O(log n), not O(n). Also O(1) is not always better than O(log n) - it depends on the size of n and the constant code complexity.

Comment: @connec: This is something that has often puzzled me, and you've made it explicit. In your question you said 'efficient method of ... access to the map', but in the comment above you said 'I doubt performance is an issue'. What exactly did you mean by efficient, if you didn't mean performance? I'm genuinely interested because I've often got the feeling that when newbies talk about efficiency they don't always strictly mean performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all strings and their handlers at compile time and want to match them in run-time, and if you don't have hell of a lot of strings and their length is not very long, and if range of possible characters in those strings is not huge (i.e. like in ASCII), then you can build a static dispatch table in compile time using templates or simply by hard-coding stuff yourself. This approach could potentially result in bad performance as well, depending on what kind of strings and how many of them you have.

Alternatively, you can have an array per string's length where a key is a sum of characters (their numeric representations) in that string.

But I'd recommend you start with Google's [`dense_hash_map`](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_map.html). Don't spend too much time prematurely optimizing your software. Once your program is done, and if you are not satisfied with performance, use profiler to find where is a bottleneck and improve performance there.

Good luck.

Comment: I think `dense_hash_map` is something I'll look at if performance becomes a concern.  At the moment I'd rather avoid the additional library.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it looks like overkill, are you trying to waste some time to optimize something that does not need to be optimized, or you are simply curious?

it depends... if function names are all know, then it all depends on the number of functions that you have. You may simply create array of string pointers in such a way so that pointers were sorted and then do manual search. If you have only a few functions in your list, then you can do linear search. If you have many, then for performance reasons, do a binary search manually (but pointers must be arranged in sorted order).

BUT, for real work, by no means use std::map! It's specifically designed for your case: insertions are expensive, but once map is created once then searches are very fast (binary search). You'll get clean correct code.

Comment: "*by no means use std::map*" Huh?

Comment: No need to do a binary search manually when `std::lower_bound` will do it for you.

Comment: Mostly curiosity :)  Definitely seems like I'll use `std::map` as the alternative seems to be writing my own hash map structure/functions xD

Comment: Mark, lover_bound is the std::impl of binary search. If somebody for some reason wants to implement it themselves, then quite likely they want to either implement both container and search algos themselves, or simply use what's available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be super efficent, you create a [parsing tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) as Plain Old data structures.   If you want to do this nicely, you create a program which generates your parsing tree from a specification (that is what [lex/flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) is doing for you), and then compile the resulting generated data structure into your program.

You then don't need a `add_handler` as all data is added at time of compilation.

That being said, you probably will not need this level of optimization for most tasks, so I would always recommend to get the functionality right first, and then look at how to optimize using such methods later.

Comment: The parser operation needs to be easily extensible though (adding new triggers/handlers for different applications), so I don't think parser generators would be a good solution.

Comment: I don't see why not -- that should just be a matter of defining a good base class for which your extensible and new classes can inherit from.

Comment: Just read your comment to @Mark answer, and if you are really only talking about a dictionary of ~10 elements, then I agree with that there is absolutely not reason to do anything else than just populate a `std::map` or `std::lower_bound` structure and then be done with it.

Comment: lower_bound is the algorithm, not a structure.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of interesting solutions based off your requirements.
A faster method than your second is to template Parser on a class who has a function pointer members for each trigger, so there is no runtime overhead at all.  In fact, it's the only solution that will allow inlining.  It does have the limitation that a single class has to have all the handlers though.

```
template<class handler>
struct Parser {
    void ParseLines() {
        if (lineBeginsWith('+')
            handler.lineBeginsPlus();
        if (lineBeginsWith('-')
            handler.lineBeginsMinus();
    }
};
struct LineHandlers {
    void lineBeginsPlus() {
        printf("handle + line");
    }
    void lineBeginsMinus() {
        printf("handle - line");
    }
};
struct OtherLineHandlers {
    void lineBeginsPlus() {
        printf("handle + line differently");
    }
    void lineBeginsMinus() {
        printf("handle - line differently");
    }
};
int main() {
    Parser<LineHandlers> ParserInstance;
    ParserInstance.ParseLines();
    Parser<OtherLineHandlers> OtherParserInstance;
    OtherParserInstance.ParseLines();
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure how this would let me automate the selection of the correct handler method based on the trigger... e.g. if the trigger was `+`, and a line beginning with `+` was encountered, I cannot have a method or variable named `+` and so I would need some other way to link the trigger to the handler (e.g. a mapping).  Though I expect I may be misunderstanding your solution?

Comment: Renamed everything to match your example there.  Also, instantiated a second class that can handle + and - lines differently.
However, if this doesn't appear to fit your situation, then go with a unordered_map of triggers to function pointers.  This solution definitely does not fit all (or even most) situations.